# Activity flags / launchmode / pendingintent

Tags: android, android-activity

i read a lot on the android documentation about launchmode and activity flags but i can't figgure it out.

i'm using the following code to open my activity from nothification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, home.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NOTIFICATION_ID++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

in the manifest i declared my home activity as

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

all works fine except for when i close my app (not only in background) only the 
onstart method gets called but not the oncreate and i have no idea why?!

i need the following:

app is open and visible to the user: user click on nothification, the existing HOME activity get active and the onnewintent gets calls (works fine)

app is in background (user pressed home button):: user click on nothification, the existing HOME activity get active and the onnewintent gets calls (works fine)

app is closed: user click on nothification, home activity gets created because its the first run! (does not work)

thanks for any help!

Comment: "app is closed" so `onDestroy` was called? or only `onStop`?

Comment: nothing, because i've killed the app with taskmanager to be sure the app is closed completely

Comment: sorry, not a taskmanager, i used http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-close-android-apps to close the app. and it seems that only onStop is called.

Comment: ok now it makes sense...  onStop was called so when coming back to foreground just onStart will be called

Comment: thx for your hint! i solved it! thx a lot!